# plot errbar {Hmisc} x axis when x is a factor R

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, r-factor

I have written this code:

```
with (data = puresa, 
      expr = errbar(Chr, Purity, Purity+sd, Purity-sd, add=F, pch=1, cap=.015))
```

It plots a plot like this:

[image]

But my goal is plotting Chr in the xlab, not in the ylab like in the above plot. The problem is that "Chr" is a factor. Because when I print it as numeric I obtain my goal:

```
with (data = puresa,
      expr =  errbar(as.numeric(Chr), Purity, Purity+sd, Purity-sd, cap=.015))
```

[image]

The problem with this last plot is that I can't replace the xlab values with the Chr names.

I am trying this code but it is not working...

```
with (data = puresa, 
      expr =  errbar(as.numeric(Chr), Purity, Purity+sd, Purity-sd,
                     xlab=if(is.character(Chr) || is.character(Chr)) "" else (substitute(Chr))))
```

[image]

I would apreciate your help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

ok I just made it!

```
par(las=2)
plot(as.numeric(puresa$Chr), puresa$Purity, type="n", xaxt = "n", ylim=c(0,1), main="Tumor purity", xlab="Chromosome", ylab="Purity")
errbar(as.numeric(puresa$Chr), puresa$Purity, puresa$Purity+puresa$sd, puresa$Purity-puresa$sd, add=T)
axis(1, at=1:25, labels=levels(puresa$Chr), cex.axis=0.8)
```

[image]

Hope it helps somebody.